# How to send notification to any device when it goes online?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I remark that when I send a message using FCM only the online devices receive the notification is there any way to send to all Devices ( the online devices and the other devices when they go online)?

Comment: I have done a full tutorial on Firebase and One signal it is on youtube , I tried it and it send even for offline (they will receive it after they become online) do you need the link?

Comment: yes please / //

Comment: Check out the solution section

Comment: If you are interested, I have exaplained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** step by step, how you can send **[notifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=17)** to specific users using Cloud Firestore and Node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted these on your request these are the implementation :

[part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZ5IQnV4otI) Firebase part

[part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cOum0Bz0Uk) One Signal Part

[part 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLSaFZ_ZfvA) One Signal Part Completion ( 2 minutes)

I think you have done part 1 since you told that you have integrated firebase but you can check them and please if it worked for you accept my solution thank you so much :) .

Comment: Awesome Work Brother it solve all my problems thank you very much!!

Comment: you are most welcome ! feel free to upvote as a support and thank you so much for trying my solution !

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to use the topic from firebase. You can find more in these two links:

[Link 1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)
[Link 2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/manage-topic-subscriptions)

Another way
is getting the listener for database changes (update that particular node value in database) from your application class and fire notification on basis of that. This will automatically do all your work, no need to send notification from server side just the listener, which will automatically destroy, and can control if your app is not in foreground.